# Locating address on Google maps

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my iPhone app , i show my home address in the table view.

When the user selects it , i want to show that location on Google map.

I have not used google map before in my applications

Please guide me that how can i achieve this functionality?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@barbgal its quit simple...only thing u need to do is to carry that data(i.e home address) from the particular index of the `UITableView` to another view(i.e mapView) and here is the example which show you how you get the location on the map which is entered by you **[see this](http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/#comment-5286)**

Hope it works for u!